# Secondary tile Animation with images in windows phone 8

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

I am able to create a secondary tile in a Windows Phone 8 app by doing this:

```
StandardTileData NewTileData = new StandardTileData
{
   BackgroundImage =new Uri(@"Shared/ShellContent/Snow.png", UriKind.Relative),
   Title = ((CheckBox)sender).Content.ToString(),
   Count = 1,
   BackBackgroundImage =new Uri(@"Shared/ShellContent/Snow.png", UriKind.Relative),
   BackTitle = "Back Title",
   BackContent = "Back Content"
};
```

Can I apply an animation for the background image? I would like to display two images scrolling vertically one after the other in the secondary tile within a period of time. Is it possible? If so, can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

No you cannot.

Check out the cycle tile instead if you want it to display pictures like that.
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj207036(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thank you.. for ur answer.. can i place primary tile as "Flip Tile" and make secondary tile as "Cyclic" tile.. is it possible..

Comment: No don't think that is possible since you specify in the WMAppManifest which tiletemplate you want to use.